# $n$-connected region, confusion with definition

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

A region $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ is called $n$-connected if $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \backslash G$ has $n+1$ components (Conway chapter 15). Consider now two regions: an annulus $A=\{r<|z|<1\}$ and an unbounded region $B$ with two holes $B = \mathbb{C} \backslash (D_1 \cup D_2)$, where $D_1, D_2$ are some disjoint closed disks.

1)  $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \backslash A = \{|z|\leq r\} \cup \{|z| \geq 1\} \cup \{\infty\}$ has two components because $\{|z| \geq 1\} \cup \{\infty\}$ is connected.

2) $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \backslash B = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup \{\infty\}$ has $3$ components.

But $A$ and $B$ are conformally equivalent, so the connectivity should be the same. Where is my mistake?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not conformally equivalent. (Unless you include $\infty$ in $B$, in which case it also becomes doubly connected, but even then they are in general not conformally equivalent because their conformal moduli might be different.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer Why not an official answer?